# creating table view using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to create a table view using swift using xcode 6 and ios8 but I am not getting anything on my simulator,simply it showing empty(white).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var myArr = ["one","two","three","four","five"]

    @IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myArr.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.myArr[indexPath.row]


        return cell;
    }

}
```

I have even tried by dragging some elements like button, switch, etc, and I am not getting anything on simulator. If I download and run any code its working.

Comment: Have you set the cell identifier to `cell` from the interface builder too?

Comment: @Isuru yes i have tried with that cell identifier also

Answer (score 2):

Here my worked code, i dont understand what was wrong in previous one,but i have created a new project then it worked.
i just dragged a table view to viewcontroller and assigned delegate and datasource
then came to viewcontroller.swift and tried

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var items = ["a","b","c"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 2
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        var cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "myCell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: No need of declaring delegate protocols again

Answer (score 1):

Is `dataSource` of `table` set in Interface builder? You can do it in code as well:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    table.dataSource = self    
}
```

Comment: even i am not getting anything on my simulator ;(

Comment: Set breakpoints in your `UITableViewDataSource` methods to see whether they are called.

Comment: Check whether delegate and dataSource are set properly. Make sure table is not nil.

Comment: i have checked but i cant find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `numberOfSectionsInTableView` from the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol:

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: No use,have tried with the above func,even its not showing :(

Answer (score 0):

Your 'table' delegate is not set. Add:

```
table.delegate = self
```

to your viewDidLoad above

```
table.dataSource = self
```

Comment: i have given but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

you missed delegate and dataSource please add following lines in viewDidLoad

table.delegate = self

and

table.dataSource = self

Comment: Np, without calling them also it has worked,thank you

Comment: That's may be due to connection in storyboard/nibs.... In this case you need not to do this